# C++11 std::thread queue consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, threadpool

I'm looking into implementing a FIFO thread queue, where thread lambdas are created, but processed at only X threads at a time.

I assume that the threads will capture some local variable, but nothing else.

A minimal example of what it is I am trying to do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <condition_variable>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::atomic<unsigned int> thread_count( 0 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock ( mutex );
        condition.wait( lock, [&]{ return thread_count < 8;} );

        std::thread t = std::thread([&,i]()
        {
            printf ("I am Thread #: %d with current thread count: %u\n", i, unsigned( thread_count ) );
            thread_count--;
        });

        threads.push_back( std::move( t ) );
        thread_count++;
    }

    for ( auto & t : threads ) t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to create thread objects/lamdas within that for loop, and then have them run 8 threads max.

Current output is:

```
I am Thread #: 0 with current thread count: 3 
I am Thread #: 3 with current thread count: 4 
I am Thread #: 2 with current thread count: 4 
I am Thread #: 5 with current thread count: 3 
I am Thread #: 1 with current thread count: 3 
I am Thread #: 4 with current thread count: 5 
I am Thread #: 6 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 7 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 8 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 9 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 10 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 11 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 12 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 13 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 14 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 15 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 16 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 17 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 18 with current thread count: 1 
I am Thread #: 19 with current thread count: 1
```

Which obviously never reaches the maximum count of 8 threads.

You can see for your self [here](http://cpp.sh/2clo)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, and what your code example has to do with the question. This also reads a little too much *gimmetehcodez*

Comment: Congratulations on realizing your desire for this code. Moving on to an actual question..

Comment: You didn't try to implement it yourself. You're just asking others to do it for you. Your answer can be found in C++ Concurrency in Action Practical Multithreading, Anthony Williams, 2012, §9.1.

Comment: @bky_drytt What do you mean I didn't try to implement it myself? The above code is what I wrote, after I got the criticism from Puppy and Barry. I am not asking anyone to spoon-feed me, but only to help on writting such a loop/mechanism/pattern. I was under the impression that this is what SO is used for. Any link or other hint would have sufficed.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry for the accusation. You should check the section of the book I pointed you to in my previous comment, because it has exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the threads you are creating are terminating faster than the main loop creates new threads. So you don't see 8 parallel threads in action but less.

Note that the program output will be non-deterministic as the thread scheduling is somewhat unpredictable. If invoked often enough, your program might actually have 8 parallel threads running from time to time...

If you change the threadfunc lambda so it does not instantly terminate, you will see the threads pile up. You can do so by adding some call to `sleep` in the threadfunc lambda.

Note that then your program might hang, because the main loop will wait for the condition variable. But no one is signalling on the condition, so it may hang forever.

So you might want to change the `thread_count--;` line at the end of your threadfunc lambda to:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock ( mutex );
thread_count--;
condition.notify_one();
```

That will not only decrement the thread count, but signal the condition variable so the main loop can wake up and resume creating extra threads if one terminates.

Full working example, with each thread sleeping for a random delay (pretending some actual work):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::condition_variable condition;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::atomic<unsigned int> thread_count(0);
    std::mt19937 generator;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock (mutex);
        condition.wait(lock, [&]{ return thread_count < 8; });
        // random sleep delay
        auto delay = generator() % 10000;

        std::thread t = std::thread([&, i, delay]() {
            printf("I am Thread #: %d with current thread count: %u\n", i, unsigned(thread_count));
            // ok to access the generator here because 
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
            printf("I am Thread #: %d and I am done\n", i);

            // signal that this thread is done
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            thread_count--;
            condition.notify_one();
        });

        threads.push_back(std::move(t));
        thread_count++;
    }

    for (auto& t : threads) {
      t.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Is this the right/correct/normal way of running a thread queue, or is there some other pattern I'm unaware of?

Comment: The thread queue above uses a mutex, so at least the creation of work items/threads is single-threaded (while work execution is not). Apart from that, creating the threads and throwing them away after doing the work will also add overhead. It may be cheaper to keep the threads around and re-use them once new work is available. Overall, instead of rolling your own thread queue, you may want to at least look for some existing and battle-tested thread pool and lock-free queue components. I won't recommend any here because which ones are best depends much on the requirements you have.